# Redshift Spectrum - Referencing an external table in a CTE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to make some data available via Redshift Spectrum to our reporting platform. I chose Spectrum because it offers lower latency to our data lake vs a batched ETL process.

One of the queries I have looks like this

```
with txns as (select * from spectrum_table where ...)
select field1, field2, ...
from txns t1
left join txns t2 on t2.id = t1.id
left join txns t3 on t3.id = t1.id
where...
```

Intuitively, this should cache the Spectrum query output in-memory with the CTE, and make it available to query later in query without hitting S3 a second (or third) time.

However, I checked the explain plan, and with each join the number of "S3 Seq Scan"s goes up by one. So it appears to do the Spectrum scan each time the CTE is queried.

Questions:

1. Is this actually happening? Or is the explain plan wrong? The run-time of this query doesn't appear to increase linearly with the number of joins, so it's hard to tell.
2. If it is happening, what other options are there to achieve this sort of result? Other than manually creating a temp table (this will be accessed by a reporting tool, so I'd prefer to avoid allowing explicit write access or requiring multiple statements to get the data)

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Amazon Redshift purely for its 'Spectrum' capabilities, you could instead consider using Amazon Athena. It has similar capabilities (querying data from S3) but is totally serverless. Performance can be improved in both cases by using Compressed, Partitioned Parquet files to reduce the amount of data read from disk.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks, but our files are already optimized for quick querying, and our tables partitioned. The issue isn't the latency of the query, it's the fact that the CTE does the same query multiple times. Athena would have the same issue.

Comment: Just theorizing here... Spectrum (and Athena) are designed for _huge_ datasets. I wouldn't expect it to keep a CTE result "in-memory". It might create a temporary result set on disk, but your EXPLAIN results even suggest that this isn't happening.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a huge deal that it's not caching the data for my purposes. I'm just trying to get answers on the expected behavior of a CTE with an external table. Typically it does try to "cache" the resultset so it doesn't need to be regenerated. Otherwise it's no different than a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes this is really happening.  CTE references are not reused - this is due to the possibility that different data will be used in the different references.  Applying where clauses at table scan is an important performance feature.
2. You could look into using a materialized view but I expect that you are dynamically applying the where clauses in the CTE so this may not match you need.  If it was me I'd want to understand why the triple self-join.  Seems like there may be a better way to construct the query but it is just a gut feel.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I chose this route because for this purpose I need minimal data lag between S3 and our reporting system, so Spectrum is the obvious choice vs a materialized view. The self-join is simply due to the nature of the data vs the report output. It is a necessary step to "denormalize" a few of the dimensions. For now I'll need to find a way to minimize joins and eat the cost of whatever is left.

Comment: In many cases self joins can be replaced with window functions (a different form of looping) which has a bit of a compute cost.  However, when input data is large is cost is greatly compensated for by the reduced IO.  It's a different way of thinking about designing queries but I've written a couple of white papers on solutions I've made for clients.

Comment: Yes, for other projects I personally have used windows e.g. to listagg fields together then regex to separate them into fields. I wasn't able to get such a paradigm to work here due to some unique logic, but maybe I should give it another shot.

Comment: Food for thought.  Here's a solution I made for a client so they could avoid a self join and really bad query performance.  I expect your situation is different but it might give you some ideas. - https://www.wadevelopment.co/sql_limits_wp_2.html